# Trigger doesn't expand my keywords

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I am a complete vim noob, that tries to get some Snippets with UltiSnips running. My minimal .vimrc is:

```
syntax on

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger='<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger='<s-tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit='vertical'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
call plug#end()
```

The preinstalled Snippets worked in :UtilsSnipetEdits. My own Snipets didn't work in my texfile. An example out of my tex Snipets is:

```
snippet beg "begin{} / end{}" bA
\begin{$1}
    $0
\end{$1}
endsnippet
```

I just tried to delete everything i used before (e.g. YouCompleteMe). Do you have some advice for trouble shooting?

Comment: First of all, remove everything that is not plugin call from in between `plug#begin()` and `plug#end()`. Those are supposed to be calls for plugin and updating `:h rtp`. Move everything else to somewhere else in your vimrc. Then read [about directories where snippets are searched in](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L202-L228). And then [read how the snippets are loaded](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L523-L585).

Comment: Please add the full path where you have saved your own snippet `beg`.

Comment: Possible location could be `~/.vim/UltiSnips/tex.snippets`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I placed the calls outside. My Snipets are in "~/UltiSnips/tex.snippets" (afaik default). I created them over the command ":UltiSnipsEdit" in a tex-file.

Comment: I added the line `set runtimepath+=~/ultisnips` but it still just tabs away :(

Comment: @GuestTimothy92 Try to add this assignment in your vimrc: `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = [$HOME . '/UltiSnips', 'UltiSnips']`.

Comment: Ah, TY! So i just got the default wrong. If g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['UltiSnips'], then it looks in `~/.vim/UltiSnips`, not in `UltiSnips` i guess. Yes, with that adjustment it just works. Sweet.